# How to pull a list of posts in a category while exluding posts in subcategories of the category

Tags: categories, get-posts

I'm using a get_posts() call to pull a list of posts in a specific category. However, the recordset also includes posts in subcategories of the target category.

How can I exclude subcategories from the query?

```
$cat = get_query_var( 'cat' );
$catHidden=get_cat_ID('hidden');
$args = array('cat' => "$cat,-$catHidden");
$myposts = get_posts($args);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `category__in` and `category__not_in` instead, it will only pull the posts that are in that category, not the subcategories as well. For your code, this would look something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'category__in'     => $cat,
    'category__not_in' => $catHidden
);
```

Note: this will only exclude posts that are directly in the category as well. If you want to exclude posts in that category and the subcategories of it, use `cat` with the negative syntax.

Also, if you need more powerful querying, this can be found with the `tax_query` parameter, which will allow you to set an `include_children` parameter for each taxonomy and term you are querying for.